# Possible to poll jQuery Ajax query?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery Ajax call which passes entered sql string and returns data rows accordingly.  Because these can be quite large amounts of data I changed the call to take a skip and no. of records parameter.  This is ok but what I really want is to list all data, as one call can return a large amount I was hoping to maybe split it up.

The process I would like to do is:

- Ajax Call to process data and store the rows somewhere
- Return the first 25 rows
- Add 25 rows to div
- Get the next 25
- Add next 25 rows to div
- etc until no more rows to add

Has anyone needed to do something like this before or has any suggestions as to how I can get a large amount of data via Ajax? For reference I'm using an ASP.Net WebMethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch more rows in the AJAX callback function. You just need to keep track how many "pages" are already there.

```
var options = { rows : 25, offset : 0, url : 'irrelevant' },
fetchRows = function(){
    $.get( options.url, { rows : options.rows, offset : options.offset  }, render );
    options.offset++;
},
render = function( data ){
  /* perform the rendering  here */

    if( data.length == options.rows ){ /* assuming `data` is an array of rows */
        fetchRows();
    }
};
```

`fetchRows` sends the AJAX request and sets `render` as the callback function. `render` then calls `fetchRows` again if previous request has returned as many rows as there can fit on one "page" (in this example last page will have < 25 rows, so there's no need to keep fetching).

Comment: Any ideas on how to run the query on first call and return the rest in chunks, rather than calling the query on each call and returning relevant data?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code - but these examples also rely on fetching data again in the callback function.